# How to use condition and multiple steps in a reactive function

Tags: mutiny

I'm currently building a reactive app using kotlin quarkus and mutiny, being new to reactive programming i wonder what's the best way to handle the following workflow :

- try to find an item in the database (dynamodb)
- if it exists return a value indicating this to the caller
- if it does not exists call the save service
- call an external service to get some data
- update the item in database with those data from the external service
- return a value indicating that the object has been created

Here's my code for now :

```
fun createCard(creationOrder: CreationOrder): Uni<CardCreationResult> {
    return creationOrdersRepository.findByOrderId(creationOrder.orderId)
        .onItem().transform {item ->
            if (item != null) {
                CardCreationResult.AlreadyCreated
            } else {
                creationOrdersRepository.save(creationOrder)

                //TODO external webservice call
                
                val cardNumber = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                creationOrdersRepository.updateCardNumberAndStatus(externalServiceCallResult)
                CardCreationResult.Created
            }
        }
}
```

This method will eventually be called by a rest endpoint.

`creationOrdersRepository.save` and `creationOrdersRepository.updateCardNumberAndStatus` returns a CompletableFuture (i'm using the quarkus amazon dynamodb client).

Is this the right way to do it ? Should i wrap the save and updateCardNumberAndStatus results in Uni (i have been trying to but keep getting type error) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe your code does what you expect. If I understand correctly you need to "save" and "update" before emitting your result. So, you need something like (in Java, as my Kotlin is not great):

```java
return creationOrdersRepository.findByOrderId(creationOrder.orderId)
  // We will be returning a Uni as the save, update and the web service are 
  // async
  .onItem().transformToUni(item -> {
    if (item != null) {
      return Uni.createFrom().item(CardCreationResult.AlreadyCreated);
    } else {
      // Create an Uni from the save operation
      Uni<Void> save = Uni.createFrom().completionStage(() -> 
        creationOrdersRepository.save(creationOrder));
      // This uni represents the invocation of the remote service
      Uni<String> webService = callWebService();

      // we chain the operations save -> web service -> update -> Created
      return save
        .chain(webService)
        .chain(externalServiceCallResult -> 
          Uni.createFrom().completionStage(() -> creationOrdersRepository
                  .updateCardNumberAndStatus(externalServiceCallResult)
        )        
        .replaceWith(CardCreationResult.Created);
    }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks but when i try the pattern you gave me i get a type error : creationOrdersRepository.save() return a CompletableFuture<PutItemResponse>,
creationOrdersRepository.updateCardNumberAndStatus() return a CompletableFuture<UpdateItemResponse>,
But chain() seems to expect a Uni with the same type as the previous Uni :
Uni<O> chain(Function<? super T, Uni<? extends O>> mapper)
Or is this a kotlin problem ?

Comment: My bad, this was indeed kotlin not managing to infer the correct signature.
Changing from .chain { myUni } to .chain { t -> myUni } fixed it, thanks !